# "Array to string conversion" errorr Laravel - Trying to save array to database

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, laravel-5

Sorry Im new to Laravel and trying to save to the database for the first time. Im trying to save an array to the database but the error "array to string conversion" is appearing. I've tried changing the string value in the migration file to other options but the same error is appearing.

Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{   
    Myroutes::create([ //posting to acc table
        'start' => $request->start,
        'end' => $request->end,
        'waypoints' => $request->waypoints
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

migration

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('myroutes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('myroute_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->string('start');
        $table->string('end');
        $table->string('waypoints');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Myroutes extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'start',
        'end',
        'waypoints'
    ];
}
```

View

```
<div id="dynamicInput" class="form-group">
                    <label>Additional Destinations</label>
                    <input type="text" name="waypoints[]" class="form-control" autocomplete="on">
                </div>
```

Database table

[database-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMVQf.png)

Comment: Is waypoints supposed to be an array? any your storing it as a string?.

Comment: I thought I need "waypoints[ ]" to make the google maps waypoints work, I've now change the name to just "waypoints", but only the first waypoint is submitting to the database. (All above code is still the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an error: `'waypoints' => $request->waypoints` won't work, as `$request->waypoints` is an array, and you can't save an array into a `VARCHAR()` field. If you `implode` the input, and convert it to a comma-separated string it should work alright:

```
`'waypoints' => implode(",", $request->waypoints`)
```

That being said, this is generally considered a bad idea; consider using relationships between `Routes` and `Waypoints` as separate tables, for both clarity and ease of use (especially in retrieving/editing.)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Will I not be able to retrieve the waypoints and have each inserted into an input field?

Comment: You can forsure, but it's extra logic to pull a string, separate by commas, etc etc, as opposed to being able to call `Route->waypoints` and retrieve a nice array of `Waypoint` models. Have a read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships; useful stuff to know regardless.

Comment: or save that as a json field in the db and cast it to array

Comment: @Indra Absolutely, a `JSON` column would work too, so long as the RDBMS supports it.

Comment: @TimLewis check out my new question on trying to get it to post from database - thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045184/array-is-saved-to-database-as-string-now-need-to-post-string-into-separate-inpu

Comment: "implode" and "explode" need a delimiter, why not using "serialize" and "unserialize" for delegating the formatting to PHP?

Comment: @PascalWirtz Yes, `serialize()` and `unserialize()` would also work (if you store the serialized value and unserialize it on retrieval), but also has the same issue that it's not the best idea. You should be able to query data, and storing the result of a PHP function generally removes the ability to do that.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected $casts = [
        'theme_setting' => 'array'
];
```

Just use casting in Model within Class

Answer (score 2):

I used this for laravel 5.8

```
$array = $request->names;
$array = implode(',', $array);
$request['names'] = $array;
$distribute = User::create($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

after form submit try to do this  :

```
dd($request->all());
```

then you will see what will be saved and will see that waypoints is array. You can't save array as string, you must to convert it to string. Variable is array because of :

```
name="waypoints[]"
```

it will not be array if you put like this :

```
name="waypoints"
```

Comment: I was was worried the google maps waypoints would not work without the squared brackets in the name. I removed it and it still works, but now only the first waypoint submits to the database as I changed it back to **'waypoints' => $request->waypoints**.

Answer (score -1):

Your Forminput "waypoints" is an Array!
So you will have to "Convert" it first before you can make the insert