# Array is saved to database as string, now need to post string into separate input fields from database - Laravel

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So this is quite a complicated question. Following on from my last question which shows how I am saving an array to the database.
["Array to string conversion" errorr Laravel - Trying to save array to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985727/array-to-string-conversion-errorr-laravel-trying-to-save-array-to-database) - I might have to change how it saves to the database to get it to show correctly.

I am using the google maps api in laravel where a user can create a route, save it (to the database) and when they are logged in can view it again and edit or delete.

The waypoints function works, so on click of the + button more input fields appear - This is how the user adds them in.

waypoints function in showing.blade

```
            var counter = 1;
            var limit = 10;
            var i = 0;
            function addInput(divName) {
              if (counter == limit) {
                alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " additional destinations");
              } else {
                var newbr = document.createElement('br');
                var newinput = document.createElement("input");
                newinput.setAttribute("name","waypoints");
                newinput.setAttribute("autocompute","on");
                newinput.setAttribute("type", "text");
                newinput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

                // newin = (counter + 1) + "<input type=text name=waypoints autocomplete=on>";
                document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newbr);
                document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newinput);
                counter++;
                i++;
                console.log("cntr=" + counter + " i=" + i + " waypoints.length=" +document.getElementsByName("waypoints"));
                // var inputw = waypoints[i];
                var autocompletew = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(newinput);
                autocompletew.setComponentRestrictions({'country':['uk','irl']});

              }
            }
```

It saves to the database as shown in myroutescontroller.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    if (Auth::check()) {

        Myroutes::create([ //posting to acc table
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'start' => $request->start,
            'end' => $request->end,
            'waypoints' => $request->waypoints
        ]);
        return redirect('/');
    } else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }   

}
```

And is showing from database in show.blade

```
                <div id="dynamicInput" class="form-group">
                    <label>Additional Destinations</label>
                    <input type="text" name="waypoints" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" value="{{ $myroute->waypoints }}">
                </div>

                <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="+" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');" style="padding:0 10px;">
```

Since the waypoints are saved as a string in the database, if the route has multiple waypoints its listing in one input field as shown in the image below.
[showing from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzLpm.png)

When it should look as follows (this is when the user creates and adds the route to database).
[adding to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSMah.png)

Any ideas and help on this will be greatly appreciated as I know its pretty complicated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Save your array as a string with `json_encode($array)` and then retrieve it `json_decode($array)`.